# Swift, how to get event click done button during play the video on AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have one **TableViewController** and I play video on that Table by tapping button inside cell to play by **AVPlayer** by code

```
@IBAction func btnFullScreen(sender: AnyObject) {    
    let playController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.presentViewController(playController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    playController.player?.play()
}
```

So, It will play the video in full screen, and also exist with **done button** on the top left. I want to get event done button, after click the **done button** it will get the current time of player to do more something else. **but how to get the event click done button?**

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible that you can intercept the Done button of AVPlayerController, a Bug Report is submitted for this with **radar: 27047358**

You can only add an observer for `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` which will be fired when your item finished playing.

Also according to the documentation:

> Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this class’s
>   methods is unsupported and results in undefined behaviour.

Reference - [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller)

Comment: thank for answer, Can you update to code for your answer?. because I try to use PlayerItemDIdReachEnd, but there is no option or name on swift 2.2

Comment: Sorry, can you try AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification

Comment: This Option cannot control  when the button done was tapped. it just control when the video was play full of video length. :(

Comment: thats what i have told you in my answer :)

Comment: @AhmadF it was possible by overriding the class methods of AVPlayerController which is not a recommended way and it is mentioned in the docs also.

Comment: @Rajat I added an incomplete comment and I delete it, just ignore it! I agree with your answer as you can see there is a vote up for it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this trick , it works on my scenario but it may give you a clue :

**Step one:**

add observers on a view controller you want to present your from there player view controller to get notified when its frame changes:

```
 self.playerViewController.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(MyViewController.view.frame), options: .new, context: nil)
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.playerViewController.player!.currentItem)
```

**Step Two:**

```
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if (keyPath ==  #keyPath(MyViewController.view.frame)){

        if playerViewController.player?.rate == 0{
            doneClicked()
        }
    }
}
```

**Step Three:**

```
    func doneClicked(){

    self.playerViewController.player!.pause()
    self.playerViewController.player!.rate =  0.0
    self.playerViewController.player = nil
    self.playerViewController.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(HomeTabViewController.view.frame))
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    self.playerViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```